# Printing from IIS not working on shared printer which connected as local asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I am trying to print using asp.net with following code

```
string s = "string to print";
PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
{
  e1.Graphics.DrawString(s, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new 
  SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, 
  p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, 
  p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
};
try
{
   p.Print();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
}
```

This code is running successfully, but not printing anything, the status in printer is always "error-printing". But it is working on my IP printer.

I assigned administrator account to Application Pool.

My environment is Server2008, IIS 7, .Net 4.0

Comment: Is it really an IP printer, or are you just using the IP address for the server name of the shared printer?

Comment: My meant was I have two printers one shared and one IP printer, code is working perfectly on IP printer but not working on shared printer

Comment: Got it. I had gone to bed just after posting the prior comment. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 0):

To use a printer shared from a remote computer, your app must run using an account that has permission to connect to the remote computer. The remote computer doesn't care at all how much permissions you have on the local workstation hosting the web server; it is a whole different security domain*, and therefore admin rights on the local station don't help at all.

To get this working, you need to set up a regular user account that *can* connect to the remote share. Often this means also changing the printer share to explicitly support the new account. Make sure this account also has permissions for the local printer and anything else your web app needs to do. Don't rely on anything that happens at user login, such as mapped drives, because this account won't log in in the normal sense. Then use the new account for the application pool.

---

<sub>* Unless both machines are joined to the same Active Directory domain, which could make things easier here.</sub>